# How do the names of methods affect execution of test cases in robotium?

Tags: robotium

How do the names of methods affect execution of test cases in robotium?

Answer (score 1):

Robotium seems to execute methods in a test class in alphabetical order. So if you precede the name of the methods by something like "test1...", test2..." etc, you can determine the proper order. However, the order should not matter for your test results. If it does, then your tests are not independent.

Comment: test1, test2, etc are not descriptive names.

Comment: No, they aren't. Feel free to use more descriptive names. Also, I said "prefix your methods by ..". I use things like test1LoginUserToServerApi, and test2RegisterUserWithFancyDescriptiveName, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Methods prefixed with the name "test" are considered tests and are executed in alphabetical order.  This is actually a functionality of JUnit, which the Android Test Framework is built on top of, and doesn't have anything to do specifically with Robotium.